# “On my holidays” - acceptable contexts

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, phrase-usage

I have been trying to determine when these can be used:

- in the holidays.
- my holidays

> 1. I will clean my room **in the holidays**.
> 2. I am going to Europe **on my holidays**.
> 3. What do you do **on your holidays**?

If correct (2 and 3), how would that differ from “on holiday”?

Answer (score 2):

My answer is from an American English perspective.

In the U.S., the word *holidays* in its plural form is rather uncommon, except when referring to the holidays around Thanksgiving (late November), Christmas, (late December), and New Years (early January). Sometimes the week between Christmas and New Years is referred to as "the holidays." It's a time when many businesses are manned with "[skeleton crews](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/skeleton-crew)."

In those cases, I think the preposition of choice would typically be *during* or *over*, not *on* or *in*:

> I am going to clean my room over the holidays.
>
> I am going to Europe during the holidays.

I find the expression "my holidays" to ring a little awkward; in the U.S. at least, we tend to favor expressions like "my vacation" or "my days off" instead.

Comment: Thanks, when I try googling, “on my holidays” seems to be Ok in certain situations: On my holidays I like to eat the local food"

Comment: @Rpp - Have you investigated further, to find out where the writer is from? I could be wrong, but that doesn't sound authored by an American.